# Is this a good approach to different tasks with if statement?

Tags: java, multithreading, android-asynctask, executorservice, java-threads

I am currently using executor services to do different 5 tasks based on if statement with different parameters and after completing the task I want update views like progress bar and textview in the user interface. My question is this approach is good or there other ways to like this?

```
 private void startTask(String studentName){

    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    if (studentName.equals("name1")){

        service.execute(taskOne("example1"));

    }else if (studentName.equals("name2")){
        
        File file = ..

        service.execute(taskTwo("example1",file));


    }else if (studentName.equals("name3")){
        
    }


}
```

Task 1 :

```
private Runnable taskOne(String p1){
        
        return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //background task
                
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        
                        //update UI
                    }
                });
                
                
            }
        };
```

Task 2 :

```
private Runnable taskTwo(String p1, File file) {
        return new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //background task
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //update UI
                    }
                });


            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not couple your business logic and UI logic in one task。 Generally, the business logic is different, but the UI logic is the same.

So, you should keep your tasks clear:

```
private Runnable taskOne(String p1) {
    return () -> {
        //background task
    };
}

private Runnable taskTwo(String p1, File file) {
    return () -> {
        //background task
    };
}
```

And abstractly maintain the UI logic:

```
private static void runTask(Runnable task, ExecutorService service) {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(task, service)
        .whenComplete((a, b) -> {
            // update UI
        });
}

private void startTask(String studentName) {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    if (studentName.equals("name1")) {
        runTask(taskOne("example1"), service);
    } else if (studentName.equals("name2")) {
        File file = ..
        runTask(taskTwo("example1", file), service);
    } else if (studentName.equals("name3")) {

    }
}
```

You use `newSingleThreadExecutor` in your code, which means your task will not concurrently run. Does that meet your expectation？

Comment: Thank you . Yes it will not work at the same time. But it is similar in some outputs only, such as hiding the progress bar, but there are other outputs, such as showing a different  alert dialog for every task